# Cannot replace \n by using fseek and fprintf in C

Tags: c, printf, newline, fseek

I tried to reposition the cursor to \n and replace it with 3, but it turned that 3 was inserted in front of \n. Then I tried fseek (fp, 2, SEEK_SET), 3 went to the beginning of next line and 2 follows. \n still existed. Can someone explain why? Or is it just because of my compiler's problem? Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (void)
{
    FILE * fp = fopen ("test2.txt", "w+");
    fprintf (fp, "1\n");
    fprintf (fp, "2\n");
    fseek (fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fseek (fp, 1, SEEK_SET); // or fseek (fp, 2, SEEK_SET);
    fprintf (fp, "3");
    fseek (fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fclose (fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason to try this with seek operations vs. writing to a buffer, manipulating as necessary, then dumping the buffer in one shot?

Comment: Are you on Windows or a CRLF platform?

Comment: Seeking to hardcoded offsets in a file opened in text mode is not supported. From the [`fseek` docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek): "*If the stream is open in text mode, the only supported values for offset are zero (which works with any origin) and a value returned by an earlier call to `ftell` (only applicable to `SEEK_SET`)*".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are apparently on Windows, where writing LF results in a writing a CR and a LF.

File before seek:

```
31 0D 0A 32 0D 0A
```

As it appears on a terminal:

```
1
2
```

File after `fseek(fp, 2, SEEK_SET)` and print:

```
31 0D 33 32 0D 0A
```

As it appears on a terminal:

```
32
```

Best to use `ftell` to get the position to which to seek.

If this is a binary file rather than a text file, make sure to open the file as binary (using the `b` modifier`).